# apache-Pig map-reduce group by error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I think I am running into a real problem now and need some expert advice.
I am running below scripts in grunt shell and everything is running fine except dump d; I am getting below error.

> `2016-03-28 20:08:30,686` [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.
>   mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!

```
--I am this script below

a = LOAD '/user/admin/pig/scripts/pig1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (pid chararray,id:int,city:chararray);  
    describe a ;  
    b = LIMIT a 100;  
    C = FOREACH a generate pid, id;  
    dump C;  
    d = group C by pid; dump d;
```

Please help.

Comment: check your load statement there is syntax error you mentioned

pid chararray but it should be like pid:chararray, correct that mistake and try, Ihope it should work fine.

Comment: ohh.. that was a typo , I tried with : only and dump see was giving some result to.. but d fails which I believe has to create multiple map reduce job and one of the job is failing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is only with `dump d;` may there is some hidden character on that line. You can use editor like BBEdit and turn on the show invisibles to see if any hidden special chars are there on this line. I tried running the script as it is and its working fine.

Comment: Just a though. dump C is working fine,.. so dump d should not have any wrong data as d is derived from c using pig script only.. ?

Comment: Thank you .. you were right.. I by mistake put a instead of b which was causing it to work on main dataset which has some unwanted values...